# Sort Spark DataFrame's column by date

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame like that:

```
+---+-------------------+
|C1 |     C2            |
+---+-------------------+
| A |21/12/2015-17-14-12|
| A |21/12/2011-20-12-44|
| B |11/02/2015-15-31-11|
| B |09/04/2015-13-38-05|  
| C |11/06/2013-23-04-35|
+---+-------------------+
```

the second column is a timestamp dd/mm/yyyy-hh-mm-ss. I would like to sort each row like that

```
+---+-------------------+
|C1 |     C2            |
+---+-------------------+
| A |21/12/2011-20-12-44|
| C |11/06/2013-23-04-35|
| B |11/02/2015-15-31-11|
| B |09/04/2015-13-38-05|  
| A |21/12/2015-17-14-12|
+---+-------------------+
```

Perhaps I have to use an Udf?Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple one-liner is all you need. Required imports

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp
```

And the code:

```
input.sort(unix_timestamp($"C2", "dd/MM/yyyy-HH-mm-ss"))
```